# I could not prove that curl of gradient is zero. How can I do this by using indiciant notation?

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

I could not find a way to equal this to zero.

$\vec{\nabla}\times(\vec{\nabla}\phi)= \epsilon_{ijk}\partial_{j}(\partial\phi)_{k}= \epsilon_{ijk}(\phi(\partial_{j}\partial_{k}) + \partial_{k}(\partial_{j}\phi)) $

Comment: Hint: interchange the order of the derivatives. If the answer is $\vec{v}$ then you can show that $\vec{v}=-\vec{v}$, which must be the zero vector.

Comment: I think I did it. Thank you!

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: “Proof” is a noun. The verb is “to prove”.

Answer (score 4):

This is virtually answered in the comments. Definitions: ${\let\del\partial}$ $$(\nabla \times F)_i = \epsilon_{ijk}\del_jF_k \\ (\nabla \phi)_k = \del_k\phi $$
Where Einstein summation is used. See also [definition of $\epsilon_{ijk}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).
then as long as $\phi\in C^2$ [(Clairaut's theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169942/why-can-partial-derivatives-be-exchanged), 
$$ (\nabla\times\nabla \phi)_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \del_j \del_k 
\phi \overset{\text{Clairaut}}{=}\epsilon_{ijk} \del_k \del_j \phi = -\epsilon_{ikj}\del_k \del_j \phi = -(\nabla\times\nabla\phi)_i$$
which implies that $\nabla\times\nabla \phi = 0$.

This has answers but they are not accepted -  [Proving the curl of a gradient is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466709/proving-the-curl-of-a-gradient-is-zero)

This is closely related, and one answer is just this proof (but phrased more tersely) - [why the curl of the gradient of a scalar field is zero? geometric interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378734/why-the-curl-of-the-gradient-of-a-scalar-field-is-zero-geometric-interpretation)